# Structure: change display depth for certain parents

Tags: add-on, structure, navigation

I'm building a site with Structure, and in my overall navigation, I'd like to vary the `show_depth` parameter for particular parts of the site.

The following works for the majority of my site's navigation:

`{exp:structure:nav css_id="none" css_class="menu" show_level_classes="yes" current_class="active" start_from="/" has_children_class="yes" show_depth="4" exclude="142|144|146|148|150|152"}`

However, there are some sections that will have many (hundreds) of entries that are also at the "fourth" level of the hierarchy that I do not want to show in the navigation. For instance: I have a "Press Releases" section, which will have a parent page (called Press Releases), and will list ALL of the site's press releases.

Is there a way to conditionally change the `show_depth` number for certain parts of the site?

Comment: Did any of the answers below help you? if so PLEASE mark one as the answer or post your own!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap simple conditionals within the `structure:nav` tag to check the segment first and then set a depth as simple conditionals are parsed before the nav tag:

```
{exp:structure:nav
    css_id="none"
    css_class="menu"
    show_level_classes="yes"
    current_class="active"
    start_from="/"
    has_children_class="yes"
    {if segment_2 == "press-release"}show_depth="3"{/if}
    {if segment_2 != "press-release"}show_depth="4"{/if}
    exclude="142|144|146|148|150|152"
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

However, wouldn't this cause unexpected display results when I'm on different pages? For instance: if I'm on the "contact" page (something like http://www.example.com/contact-us) where `segment_2` was "contact-us", the display depth in the navigation would be incorrect for the "press-release" stack. Does that make sense? We may be misunderstanding one another.

Comment: The conditionals were just an example of how you can control the `show_depth` parameter based off the segment. So, you might need to add more simple conditionals to get the desired output based off segment

Answer (score 0):

You're much better off using the `start_from`parameter for each section of your nav that you would like to display on the front-end, like so:

```
{exp:structure:nav
        css_id="none"
        css_class="menu
        show_level_classes="yes"
        current_class="active"
        has_children_class="yes"
        show_depth="XXX"
        max_depth="XXX"
        start_from="/press-releases"
    }
    {exp:structure:nav
        css_id="none"
        css_class="menu
        show_level_classes="yes"
        current_class="active"
        has_children_class="yes"
        show_depth="XXX"
        max_depth="XXX"
        start_from="/SECTION-ONE"
    }
    {exp:structure:nav
        css_id="none"
        css_class="menu
        show_level_classes="yes"
        current_class="active"
        has_children_class="yes"
        show_depth="XXX"
        max_depth="XXX"
        start_from="/SECTION-TWO"
    }
```

Of course for each "SECTION" you'll need to use your own page names to get those to output. This gives a bit more flexibility for how you want your navigation to appear on the site.

I almost forgot that you'll also need to use the `max_depth` parameter as well.